# AppDelegate to call function from m File + presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, appdelegate

I have a `AdIntegrator.mm` file that contains a function to create a form:

```
 -(void)createAndDisplayForm{
     AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];          //add AppDelegate pointer
     _vc = app.window.rootViewController;

    //create form

    //presented using presentFromViewController:_vc
 }
```

I would like to be able to use this form again, from my `AppDelegate.mm` when I need to, (should the `User` wish to see this form again).

How can I call this?

I tried the following from my `AppDelegate.mm`, but no view was displayed:

```
AdIntegrator* opt = [[AdIntegrator alloc] init];
[opt createAndDisplayForm];
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to use this function from the AppDelegate as well as making sure the presentFromViewController can be seen again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well let me explain, the **AppDelegate** is a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) object, so you can declare the **AdIntegrator** class in **AppDelegate.h** like this:

```
#import "AdIntegrator.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic) AdIntegrator *adIntegratorObject;

@end
```

In your AppDelegate.m you need to do this:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    _AdIntegrator = [[AdIntegrator alloc] init];
    // or like this [AdIntegrator new];

    return YES;
}
```

The **_AdIntegrator** object is the reference in the AppDelegate singleton
 to call the method from everywhere, so you can do this from **OtherViewController.m** you need to **#import "AppDelegate.h"** in the OtherViewController.m to see the object and call the method:

```
- (void)methodExampleFromOtherViewController
{
    AppDelegate *appObject = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Calling your method in adIntegratorObject class
    [appObject.adIntegratorObject YOUR_METHOD_CALL];
}
```

You can use the **presentViewController:animated:completion:** method with the **AdIntegrator** object calling from **AppDelegate** cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The code compiles, but for some reason it's not calling the function. I put an `NSLog` right at the start and it's not getting that far. I also had to use `[AdIntegrator new];`

Comment: I modified the files AppDelegate.h to #import "AdIntegrator.h" and now the method is visible, sorry my buddy, I hope it helps you :)

Comment: In the future you can create your own singleton class and declare in the AppDelegate.h singleton like this and use the others class in that object, because you don't want to import many classes in the AppDelegate.h :D